# Question about JPanel cover the whole area of BorderLayout when using BorderLayout.CENTER

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel, border-layout

I am trying to set a **BorderLayout** of my JFrame.

Firstly create a **FlowLayout** with two JButtons. Then add the FlowLayout the top of BorderLayout. It works correctly according to my code.

Secondly, I created a **MyPanel** object which is inherited from **JPanel**. There is a **MouseAdapter** to realize when the mouse left click panel output mouse coordinates.

Everything works fine but I found the MouseEvent will be listened and output the coordinate wherever I click the mouse except the top panel.

My question is: Wouldn't the mouse event be triggered only if I clicked on the middle part of the frame, because I added the mouse listener to MyPanel, which was added to the **CENTER** position of BorderLayout.

Following is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    public MyPanel() {
        //anonymous class to listen mouse 
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                //if left click
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                    //print location message
                    System.out.println("Left button clicked at position (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    public MyFrame() {
        //initial settings of frame
        this.setSize(400, 300);
        this.setTitle("MyFrame Title");
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //set layout of frame
        BorderLayout l1 = new BorderLayout();
        this.setLayout(l1);
        
        //set top panel
        JPanel top = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        //buttons in top panel
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Left");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Right");
        //add to top of frame
        this.add(top,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        
        //add my panel to center of frame
        MyPanel center = new MyPanel();
        this.add(center,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //add buttons
        top.add(b1);
        top.add(b2);
        
        //make it visible
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the MouseEvent is only listened when I click on the center part of the Frame. I was wondering if the JPanel that is added to the CENTER section automatically extends to other areas that are not occupied if the rest of the BorderLayout has no components, is that right?

Comment: Oh! Roger that, thank you for your explaination!